# Python Custom Tkinter. Hover effect on buttons when selected with Tabulator key

Tags: python, tkinter, button, hover

So I have used `.bind()` on all my buttons and basically I would like to see which button is currently 'selected' when I switch between them with tabulator key. I did spend already quite a while on search for solution but didn't found anything useful. I don't know how to grab that moment when after pressing Tab key focus is on a button.

When there is more widgets I can `.bind()` Tab key to a widget proceeding button to simply just change foreground of a button but this won't work in case when I have only buttons in frame because first button will be omitted and that's not a clean and right solution to my issue.
If I bind Tab key to that button and change foreground then it's changed but after pressing Tab when button was already selected.
I don't know is there any clean solution for that problem or I will have to for frames that have only buttons create some starting_dummy widget that would initiate change for a first button.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: This is usually called "focus", have you tried the events `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>`?

Comment: @ivvija I tried `focus_get()` in function called from `root.bind_all()` by lambda in it, but it gives me feed back only on mouse click and it's tricky. With Tab key it didn't work beside giving a dot at the start of program. For now I'll use Tk instead of CTk just for buttons because it highlight selected button in base version, so I'll try customize my own buttons and I hope they will keep the highlight. But sill I'll be trying to work my way with this CTk buttom issue and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a way to detect is Tab key focused at this moment on a particular button (like it is with `hover` and cursor) but I know when it's going to be so I used that and solved case with only buttons in frame. It's based on what I already wrote in the question - I'm binding Tab key with a function to a widget preceding button to change button colour while button is bind to a function that's changing colour back to normal like this:

```
    self.entry.bind("<Tab>", self.focus_in)
    self.button.bind('<Tab>', self.focus_out)

def focus_in(self, event):
    self.button.configure(fg_color='white')

def focus_out(self, event):
    self.button.configure(fg_color='black')
```

For the case when only widgets in the frame/root are buttons, like in a menu that I got first I `focus_set()` on the last button and make a functions that circulate colours on and off at on Tab like this:

```
    self.button2.focus_set()

    self.button1.bind('<Tab>', self.focus_in)
    self.button2.bind('<Tab>', self.focus_out)

def focus_out(self, event):
    self.button1.configure(fg_color='white')
    self.button2.configure(fg_color='black')

def focus_in(self, event):
    self.button1.configure(fg_color='black')
    self.button2.configure(fg_color='white')
```

Whit a custom made buttons it's just matter of replacing `fg_color` with a `image`.
If you use a button as an image holder for your logo or so, then just set `state='disabled'` and it will be omitted.